# wonderful code, need help loading the arrays

Tags: c#, polygon, nullreferenceexception, enumeration

when i attempt to load the polygon with points, i get a null reference exception...

look at the simplerectangle loading, i'm sure this probably not correct...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{

    public class GeometryFunctions
    {
        public class PointF
        {
            public double X;
            public double Y;
            public PointF(double _X, double _Y) { X = _X; Y = _Y; }
            public static PointF operator +(PointF p1, PointF p2) { return new PointF(p1.X + p2.X, p1.Y + p2.Y); }
            public static PointF operator -(PointF p1, PointF p2) { return new PointF(p1.X - p2.X, p1.Y - p2.Y); }
            public static PointF operator *(double Multiplier, PointF p1) { return new PointF(Multiplier * p1.X, Multiplier * p1.Y); }
            public static PointF operator *(PointF p1, double Multiplier) { return new PointF(Multiplier * p1.X, Multiplier * p1.Y); }
            public static PointF operator /(PointF p1, double Divisor) { return new PointF(p1.X / Divisor, p1.Y / Divisor); }
        }

        public struct Line
        {
            public static Line Empty;

            private PointF p1;
            private PointF p2;

            public Line(PointF p1, PointF p2)
            {
                this.p1 = p1;
                this.p2 = p2;
            }

            public PointF P1
            {
                get { return p1; }
                set { p1 = value; }
            }

            public PointF P2
            {
                get { return p2; }
                set { p2 = value; }
            }

            public double X1
            {
                get { return p1.X; }
                set { p1.X = value; }
            }

            public double X2
            {
                get { return p2.X; }
                set { p2.X = value; }
            }

            public double Y1
            {
                get { return p1.Y; }
                set { p1.Y = value; }
            }

            public double Y2
            {
                get { return p2.Y; }
                set { p2.Y = value; }
            }
        }

        public struct Polygon : IEnumerable<PointF>
        {
            private PointF[] points;

            public Polygon(PointF[] points)
            {
                this.points = points;
            }

            public PointF[] Points
            {
                get { return points; }
                set { points = value; }
            }

            public int Length
            {
                get { return points.Length; }
            }

            public PointF this[int index]
            {
                get { return points[index]; }
                set { points[index] = value; }
            }

            public static implicit operator PointF[](Polygon polygon)
            {
                return polygon.points;
            }

            public static implicit operator Polygon(PointF[] points)
            {
                return new Polygon(points);
            }

            IEnumerator<PointF> IEnumerable<PointF>.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return (IEnumerator<PointF>)points.GetEnumerator();
            }

            public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
            {
                return points.GetEnumerator();
            }
        }

        public enum Intersection
        {
            None,
            Tangent,
            Intersection,
            Containment
        }

        public static class Geometry
        {

            public static Intersection IntersectionOf(Line line, Polygon polygon)
            {
                if (polygon.Length == 0)
                {
                    return Intersection.None;
                }
                if (polygon.Length == 1)
                {
                    return IntersectionOf(polygon[0], line);
                }
                bool tangent = false;
                for (int index = 0; index < polygon.Length; index++)
                {
                    int index2 = (index + 1) % polygon.Length;
                    Intersection intersection = IntersectionOf(line, new Line(polygon[index], polygon[index2]));
                    if (intersection == Intersection.Intersection)
                    {
                        return intersection;
                    }
                    if (intersection == Intersection.Tangent)
                    {
                        tangent = true;
                    }
                }
                return tangent ? Intersection.Tangent : IntersectionOf(line.P1, polygon);
            }

            public static Intersection IntersectionOf(PointF point, Polygon polygon)
            {
                switch (polygon.Length)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return Intersection.None;
                    case 1:
                        if (polygon[0].X == point.X && polygon[0].Y == point.Y)
                        {
                            return Intersection.Tangent;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return Intersection.None;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        return IntersectionOf(point, new Line(polygon[0], polygon[1]));
                }

                int counter = 0;
                int i;
                PointF p1;
                int n = polygon.Length;
                p1 = polygon[0];
                if (point == p1)
                {
                    return Intersection.Tangent;
                }

                for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                {
                    PointF p2 = polygon[i % n];
                    if (point == p2)
                    {
                        return Intersection.Tangent;
                    }
                    if (point.Y > Math.Min(p1.Y, p2.Y))
                    {
                        if (point.Y <= Math.Max(p1.Y, p2.Y))
                        {
                            if (point.X <= Math.Max(p1.X, p2.X))
                            {
                                if (p1.Y != p2.Y)
                                {
                                    double xinters = (point.Y - p1.Y) * (p2.X - p1.X) / (p2.Y - p1.Y) + p1.X;
                                    if (p1.X == p2.X || point.X <= xinters)
                                        counter++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    p1 = p2;
                }

                return (counter % 2 == 1) ? Intersection.Containment : Intersection.None;
            }

            public static Intersection IntersectionOf(PointF point, Line line)
            {
                double bottomY = Math.Min(line.Y1, line.Y2);
                double topY = Math.Max(line.Y1, line.Y2);
                bool heightIsRight = point.Y >= bottomY &&
                                     point.Y <= topY;
                //Vertical line, slope is divideByZero error!
                if (line.X1 == line.X2)
                {
                    if (point.X == line.X1 && heightIsRight)
                    {
                        return Intersection.Tangent;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Intersection.None;
                    }
                }
                double slope = (line.X2 - line.X1) / (line.Y2 - line.Y1);
                bool onLine = (line.Y1 - point.Y) == (slope * (line.X1 - point.X));
                if (onLine && heightIsRight)
                {
                    return Intersection.Tangent;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Intersection.None;
                }
            }

            public static Intersection IntersectionOf(Line line1, Line line2)
            {
                //  Fail if either line segment is zero-length.
                if (line1.X1 == line1.X2 && line1.Y1 == line1.Y2 || line2.X1 == line2.X2 && line2.Y1 == line2.Y2)
                    return Intersection.None;

                if (line1.X1 == line2.X1 && line1.Y1 == line2.Y1 || line1.X2 == line2.X1 && line1.Y2 == line2.Y1)
                    return Intersection.Intersection;
                if (line1.X1 == line2.X2 && line1.Y1 == line2.Y2 || line1.X2 == line2.X2 && line1.Y2 == line2.Y2)
                    return Intersection.Intersection;

                //  (1) Translate the system so that point A is on the origin.
                line1.X2 -= line1.X1; line1.Y2 -= line1.Y1;
                line2.X1 -= line1.X1; line2.Y1 -= line1.Y1;
                line2.X2 -= line1.X1; line2.Y2 -= line1.Y1;

                //  Discover the length of segment A-B.
                double distAB = Math.Sqrt(line1.X2 * line1.X2 + line1.Y2 * line1.Y2);

                //  (2) Rotate the system so that point B is on the positive X axis.
                double theCos = line1.X2 / distAB;
                double theSin = line1.Y2 / distAB;
                double newX = line2.X1 * theCos + line2.Y1 * theSin;
                line2.Y1 = line2.Y1 * theCos - line2.X1 * theSin; line2.X1 = newX;
                newX = line2.X2 * theCos + line2.Y2 * theSin;
                line2.Y2 = line2.Y2 * theCos - line2.X2 * theSin; line2.X2 = newX;

                //  Fail if segment C-D doesn't cross line A-B.
                if (line2.Y1 < 0 && line2.Y2 < 0 || line2.Y1 >= 0 && line2.Y2 >= 0)
                    return Intersection.None;

                //  (3) Discover the position of the intersection point along line A-B.
                double posAB = line2.X2 + (line2.X1 - line2.X2) * line2.Y2 / (line2.Y2 - line2.Y1);

                //  Fail if segment C-D crosses line A-B outside of segment A-B.
                if (posAB < 0 || posAB > distAB)
                    return Intersection.None;

                //  (4) Apply the discovered position to line A-B in the original coordinate system.
                return Intersection.Intersection;
            }


        } 


        public void findthatintersectingpoint()
        {
            PointF pt0 = new PointF(5.0, 5.0);
            PointF pt1 = new PointF(10.0, 5.0);
            PointF pt2 = new PointF(10.0, 10.0);
            PointF pt3 = new PointF(5.0, 10.0);

            Polygon simplerectangle = new Polygon();
            simplerectangle[0] = pt0; simplerectangle[1] = pt1; simplerectangle[2] = pt2; simplerectangle[3] = pt3;

            PointF linestart = new PointF(2.0, 2.0);
            PointF lineend = new PointF(12.0, 12.0);
            Line myline = new Line(lineend, linestart);           

            Intersection intersection = Geometry.IntersectionOf(myline, simplerectangle);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace for the exception.

Comment: Also, [evil mutable structs!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/441309/3317555)